# Mouse Hover Not Working

Tags: macos, mouse, mac

This may be a simple question, but for a long time now Safari has not registered when my mouse is hovering over something (e.g. hover over a youtube video to show the progress bar, hover over a link to highlight it, hover over the FaceBook like button to show different reactions, etc.).

Does anyone have any insight into a solution? I've restarted multiple times since this started occuring.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, it mostly happens when open a website from Favourite List in a new tab. I've reported the problem to Apple months ago, it's still not fixed in 10.14.5.

Comment: Pressing `option` gets the mouse to be recognised (once) but I still encounter the problem when loading the Website manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anyas Marshal stated in a comment, the issue truly did happen when I opened a website from my Favorites list in a new tab. I stopped doing that and I never experienced the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

I restored my Logitech settings from a backup and the problem went away.

Something must have gotten corrupted.

I have an M720 Triathlon Multi-device Mouse and a K780 Multi-device keyboard.